# "Octahedron" made from two pyramids of different heights.

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d, polyhedra

I wonder how to name such shape:

[image]

It's commonly used by e.g. 3ds max to visualize the bone in animation system. 
It consist of two pyramids with the exact same square base. 
It *would be a octahedron*, but the pyramids have different heights.
**What's the proper name for such 3d shape?** If none exists, how should I call such geometry in my 3d engine (it's not only associated with bones and animation)?

Comment: It's an octahedron, just not a regular octahedron.

Comment: @vadim123 Ah, you're right. Can you make it an answer? P.s. I've also heard the term "bipyramid", but I guess I should just call it (irregular) octahedron.

Comment: It's not a bipyramid, the two pyramids are mirror images of one another in a bipyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I am copying my comment as an answer.  The shape is an octahedron, just not a regular octahedron.

Answer (score 0):

It is a unilateral octahedron.